# Karma TestRunner

Tags: unit-testing, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I have the testRunner Karma opened for my Angular app. There is an issue with the window, on the right corner of the test runner, it shows 'finished in NaNs' . As I understand, it should show how much time it took to run the test. Does anybody know how to fix it? Thank you

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('karma-spec-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true,
    },

    specReporter: {
      maxLogLines: 5,
      showSpecTiming: false,

    },


    reportSlowerThan: 1,
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml', 'coverage-istanbul', 'spec'],
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    restartOnFileChange: true,

  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

found a reason why I got that bug. It is related to the current version of code-jasmine, had to go to the previous version to make it work